# How override default admin static files?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can I override default admin static files - for example icon_error.png, icon_success.png ?

Comment: You mean you want to use different images? Or that you want to change the values displayed by the template?

Comment: I want to use different images. I don't want change templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it depends on how much you want to overwrite.

If you create an admin directory under your static directory those files will be read before the actual admin files.

if this is your structure:

```
root
  appname
    static
      css
      js
```

you should create it like this:

```
root
  appname
    static
      admin
        img
          icon_success.gif
      css
      js
```

Name has to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

The django package is hosted on your server. Have you considered changing the images for `icon_error.png` and `icon_success.png`, then resaving them with the same name on your filesystem?

The location where you can find the static image files within the django package is:

`/ django / django / contrib / admin / static / admin / img /`

Comment: You should never change the core files.